# Spring bean property population through init method

Tags: java, spring

I have one question regarding spring beans initialization. What would be the scneario when we are populating bean property through init methods. Have a look at given below code snippet. Here I am populating super class bean property list through init method.

1) Super class Bean :

```
public class Super  {
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    public void setList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }
    public void init(){
     System.out.println("Super init called");
     populateList();
     System.out.println("Super list"+list.size());
    }
    public void populateList(){
        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
    }
    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

2) Bean 2 :

```
public class Sub extends Super {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("conf/appXml/init-test.xml");
        Sub utils = (Sub)ctx.getBean("sub");

        System.out.println("Sub list:::"+utils.getList().size());
        for(String s : utils.getList()){
            System.out.println("Value::::" +s);
        }
    }
}
```

3) Spring-context xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id = "super" class = "com.hitesh.springtest.Super" init-method="init">
    </bean>
    <bean id = "sub" class = "com.hitesh.springtest.Sub"></bean>    
    </beans>
```

4) Output :
    Super init called
    Super list2
    Sub list:::0

My question is when super class is getting initialized by container the init() is called. In this method the list object is populated. Now when sub class instantiation is completed why we are getting list size as 0, as we are referring to very same list object which has been populated in super bean initialization. Can somebody explain this ?

Answer (score 3):

It is not the `very same list object`. There are two objects in you context: `super` and `sub`. Since `list` is an instance field two instances of the `list` object exist, one for `super` and one for `sub`. The one for `sub` was never initialized because the `init-method` was not set for that bean.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say, instead of spring, you are initializing the objects (*loosely on lines of spring container*), the code would look something like this

```
Super super = new Super();
super.init();

Sub sub = new Sub();

//now if you say 
sub.getList().size();
//This will always print size zero as you never initialized the super class collection.
```

So there are two different objects. Spring does not inherit the properties of the superclass if its defined as *another* bean.

Answer (score 0):

You see "Super list2" because Spring is creating a `bean` with `id = "super"` and it's calling the `init-method`  when it creates it as defined in your `Spring-context.xml`.

When Spring creates `bean id = "sub"`, it's not calling the `init-method` because there isn't one specified. If you add the `init-method` to the definition of the `sub` bean, you should see the behavior you're expecting.

Comment: You missed this statement: `we are referring to very same list object which has been populated in super bean initialization` which shows the error in the OP's thinking